# how to sort tuples of list with a special condition?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have two list `underdraw` and `rate`. They both contain 20 elements.

```
underdraw = [0,20,23,0,23,0,0,0,55,4,3,10,0,0,0,0,23,45,56,0]
rate = [0,201,43,0,123,0,0,0,0,43,35,120,0,0,0,0,253,5,0,0]
```

I divided the underdraw list into two lists further `underLimit` and `beyondLimit` and the limit is `25`.

```
underLimit = [i if i <= 25 else 0 for i in underdraw]
beyondLimit = [i if i > 25 else 0 for i in underdraw]
```

now I combined these two lists with the `rate`

```
combinedLimits1 = list(zip(underLimit, rate))
combinedLimits2 = list(zip(beyondLimit, rate))
```

Now there are 20 tuples inside these two lists `combinedList1` and `combinedList2`. I want to catogorized them into 5 sets.

```
n = 5
x = [combinedLimits1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(combinedLimits1), n)]
y = [combinedLimits2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(combinedLimits2), n)]
```

If you print the blocks of x and y

```
x=[(0, 0), (20, 201), (23, 43), (0, 0), (23, 123)]#list1
  [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (4, 43)]#list2
  [(3, 35), (10, 120), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]#list3
  [(0, 0), (23, 253), (0, 5), (0, 0), (0, 0)]#list4

y=[(0, 0), (0, 201), (0, 43), (0, 0), (0, 123)]#list1
  [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (55, 0), (0, 43)]#list2
  [(0, 35), (0, 120), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]#list3
  [(0, 0), (0, 253), (45, 5), (56, 0), (0, 0)]#list4
```

Now I want to sort this `x` and `y` in increasing rate order and took the smallest 3 values from it and take only those values in comparison when THERE IS A VALUE IN UNDERDRAW.
Expected output(for x):
Smallest 3 rates(if there is no rate then just put 20 there)

```
[(23,43), (23, 123), (20, 201)]#list1
[(4,43), (0, 20), (0, 20)]#list2
[(3,35), (10, 120), (0, 20)]#list3
[(23,253), (0, 20), (0, 20)]#list4
y=
[(0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20)]#list1
[(50, 0), (0, 20), (0, 20)]#list2
[(0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20)]#list3
[(56, 0), (45, 5), (0, 20)]#list4
```

So basically it is sorting only when there is a value in underdraw and as I required 3 min values so, if there are no min 3 elements then just simple put rate = 20 there. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with `filter` and `sorted`:

```
underdraw = [0,20,23,0,23,0,0,0,55,4,3,10,0,0,0,0,23,45,56,0]
rate = [0,201,43,0,123,0,0,0,0,43,35,120,0,0,0,0,253,5,0,0]
underLimit = [i if i <= 25 else 0 for i in underdraw]
beyondLimit = [i if i > 25 else 0 for i in underdraw]
combinedLimits1 = list(zip(underLimit, rate))
combinedLimits2 = list(zip(beyondLimit, rate))
n = 5
x = [combinedLimits1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(combinedLimits1), n)]
y = [combinedLimits2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(combinedLimits2), n)]
newx=[sorted(list(filter(lambda y: y[0]!=0,ls)),key=lambda h: h[1]) for ls in x]
newx=[ls if len(ls)==3 else ls+[(0,20)]*(3-len(ls)) for ls in newx ]
newy=[sorted(list(filter(lambda y: y[0]!=0,ls)),key=lambda h: h[1]) for ls in y]
newy=[ls if len(ls)==3 else ls+[(0,20)]*(3-len(ls)) for ls in newy ]
print(newx)
print(newy)
```

Output:

```
newx
[[(23, 43), (23, 123), (20, 201)], [(4, 43), (0, 20), (0, 20)], [(3, 35), (10, 120), (0, 20)], [(23, 253), (0, 20), (0, 20)]] 

newy
[[(0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20)], [(55, 0), (0, 20), (0, 20)], [(0, 20), (0, 20), (0, 20)], [(56, 0), (45, 5), (0, 20)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> now I combined these two lists with the rate
>
> ```
> combinedLimits1 = list(zip(underLimit, rate))
> combinedLimits2 = list(zip(beyondLimit, rate))
> ```

Are you sure that makes sense? Since `underdraw` and `rate` are the same lengths I'd have assumed they matched, this is going to combine the first n rates with what's under the limit, and the first k rates with above (where n and k are the number of items respectively under and above the limit).

> Now there are 20 tuples inside these two lists combinedList1 and combinedList2. I want to catogorized them into 5 sets.

That's just chunking though, not categorisation.

> Now I want to sort this x and y in increasing rate order and took the smallest 3 values from it and take only those values in comparison when THERE IS A VALUE IN UNDERDRAW. Expected output(for x): Smallest 3 rates(if there is no rate then just put 20 there)

So... take the first 3 items with a non-zero underdraw (they all have a value) ordered by ascending rate, pad with `(0, 20)` to 3 items if necessary?

```
# remove entries with underdraw = 0, sort by rate
items = sorted(((d, r) for d, r in lst if d != 0), key=lambda item: item[1])
# we now have 0~5 items, cut down to size
items = items[:3]
# pad with however many (0, 20) items are missing to go to 3
items += [(0, 20)] * (3 - len(items))
```

Comment: Hey thanks, Now I understand the points that you had made but there are two things: One, what is the output which we are getting from your code and second, I combined those lists because in further calculations I wanted to know respective underdraw along with the Rate.

Comment: "One, what is the output which we are getting from your code" you gave the output you were expecting, what else would it be?

Comment: "I combined those lists because in further calculations I wanted to know respective underdraw along with the Rate" my concern is not *that* you combined those lists, it's *how* you combined them, but since you don't explain what these things are it might be unfounded: since the lists are of the same length, I would have expected each rate to "pair" with the corresponding underdraw, but that's now at all how your code is using them

Answer (score 1):

```
# Code (edited) from geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-item/
def sortTuple(tup):  
    tup.sort(key = lambda i: i[1])
    return tup  

# You can repeat this same thing for the y list
for index, sublist in enumerate(x):
    orderedSublist = sortTuple(sublist)

    for element in orderedSublist.copy():
        if element[1] == 0:
            orderedSublist.append(orderedSublist.pop(0))
            orderedSublist[-1] = (orderedSublist[-1][0], 20)  # You can't mutate (edit) tuples so we create a new one

    orderedSublist = orderedSublist[:3]  # Taking the smallest 3 elements (excluding 0s)
    x[index] = orderedSublist
```

The code is essentially going through every sublist in x and sorting that according to the second element of the tuple. This is sorted in a way that the 0s come at the beginning as well so we go through every element in the ordered list and shift all the tuples with the rate being 0 to the back.

Finally, we just take the first 3 elements and print out the list.